# Скрытый выдвижной текст

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

http://intellect-media.biz/seo-prodvizhenie/ - мой

https://atom-media.ru/seo/ - донор

Не получается реализовать такую же выдвижную таблицу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо так же, а у меня почему-то поплыло. Какие надо правки?

Вот html:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
<div id="seo-accordion" class="page__serviceitem__faq" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false">
<div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item">
<div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__toggle__number">01</div>
<span id="heading1">Оптимизация сайта</span>
<div id="collapse1" class="collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading1">
<div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__descr">

1.1. Внедрение систем аналитики, их настройка под цели клиента (Google Analytics, Яндекс Метрика, цели, электронная торговля, отслеживание посещаемости и структуры трафика).

1.2. Проверка сайта на пессимизацию поисковыми системами и устранение потенциальной угрозы санкций.

1.3. Техническая оптимизация сайта (скорость и корректность работы, индексация сайта и его представление в поиске).

1.4. Работа с сервисами для вебмастеров с целью улучшения представления сайта в поиске (Яндекс. Вебмастер, Google Webmaster, Вебмастер mail.ru).

1.5. Внутренняя оптимизация (Подготовка и размещение текстов на сайте, прописание заголовков h1-h3, тегов, внутренняя перелинковка).

1.6. Анализ коммерческих факторов (необходимые в данной тематике коммерческая информация — цены, условия работы, выгоды и дополнительная ценность сайта).

1.7. Анализ социальных сигналов (наличие и активность аккаунтов в социальных сетях).

1.8. Анализ поведенческих факторов (сниппеты сайта по запросам, кликабельность в выдаче, поведенческие метрики на сайте).

</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item">
<div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__toggle__number">02</div>
<span id="heading2">Внешняя оптимизация</span>
<div id="collapse2" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading2">
<div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__descr">

2.1. Создание проекта в бирже ссылок.

2.2. Внесение продвигаемых страниц.

2.3. Составление анкоров.

2.4. Закупка ссылок в бирже ссылок.

2.4.1 Подбор сайтов-доноров.

2.4.2 Проверка индексации в поисковых системах.

2.4.3 Проверка количества внешних ссылок.

2.4.4 Проверка количества внутренних ссылок.

2.4.5 Проверка текстового наполнения сайта.

2.4.6 Проверка посещаемости.

</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item">
<div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__toggle__number">03</div>
<span id="heading3">Анализ конкурентов</span>
<div id="collapse3" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading3">
<div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__descr">

3.1. Подбор 4-5 основных конкурентов сайта в интернете.

3.2. Анализ конкурентов с целью поиска сильных мест конкурентов.

3.3. Подготовка технического задания на доработку сайта по результатам анализа конкурентов.

</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item">
<div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__toggle__number">04</div>
<span id="heading4">Юзабилити аудит</span>
<div id="collapse4" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading4">
<div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__descr">

4.1. Анализ основных страниц сайта.

4.2. Анализ конверсионных путей.

4.3. Анализ действия посетителей в корзине.

4.4. Анализ карт поведения посетителей, видеозаписей их активности на сайте.

4.5. Тестирование нововведений при необходимости.

4.6. Подготовка технического задания по результатам юзабилити аудита и контроль внедрения.

</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item">
<div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__toggle__number">05</div>
<span id="heading5">Мониторинг</span>
<div id="collapse5" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading5">
<div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__descr">Мониторинг позиций сайта в поисковых системах, посещаемости, конверсий.
Фиксация основных параметров сайта и их отслеживание.</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item">
<div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__toggle__number">06</div>
<span id="heading6">Отчеты</span>
<div id="collapse6" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading6">
<div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__descr">

Ежемесячное составление отчетов.

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1"></div>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы сделал вот так:

```js
$('.page__serviceitem__faq__item__toggle').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.page__serviceitem__faq__item').find('.page__serviceitem__faq__item__descr').slideToggle(400).toggleClass('active');
  $(this).closest('.page__serviceitem__faq__item').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.page__serviceitem__faq__item {
  border: 1px solid #DFE8EF;
}

.page__serviceitem__faq__item__toggle {
  display: block;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 21px 0 21px 114px;
  transition: all 250ms;
  color: #27323A;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.page__serviceitem__faq__item__toggle.collapsed {
  background-color: #F2F6F9;
}

.page__serviceitem__faq__item__toggle__number {
  position: absolute;
  left: 29px;
  top: 0;
  color: #DFE8EF;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
}

.page__serviceitem__faq__item__toggle span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.page__serviceitem__faq__item__toggle span::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px dashed #27323A;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.page__serviceitem__faq__item__descr {
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 0 50px 22px 114px;
  display: none;
}

.in .page__serviceitem__faq__item__descr {
  display: block;
}

.page__serviceitem__faq__item .collapse {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="seo-accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false" class="page__serviceitem__faq">
  <div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item in">
    <a class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__toggle">
      <div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__toggle__number">01</div>
      <span id="heading1">Оптимизация сайта</span>
    </a>
    <div id="collapse1" class="collapse">
      <div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__descr"> 1.1. Внедрение систем аналитики, их настройка под цели клиента (Google Analytics, Яндекс Метрика, цели, электронная торговля, отслеживание посещаемости и структуры трафика).
        <p></p>
        <p> 1.2. Проверка сайта на пессимизацию поисковыми системами и устранение потенциальной угрозы санкций.</p>
        <p> 1.3. Техническая оптимизация сайта (скорость и корректность работы, индексация сайта и его представление в поиске).</p>
        <p> 1.4. Работа с сервисами для вебмастеров с целью улучшения представления сайта в поиске (Яндекс. Вебмастер, Google Webmaster, Вебмастер mail.ru).</p>
        <p> 1.5. Внутренняя оптимизация (Подготовка и размещение текстов на сайте, прописание заголовков h1-h3, тегов, внутренняя перелинковка).</p>
        <p> 1.6. Анализ коммерческих факторов (необходимые в данной тематике коммерческая информация — цены, условия работы, выгоды и дополнительная ценность сайта).</p>
        <p> 1.7. Анализ социальных сигналов (наличие и активность аккаунтов в социальных сетях).</p>
        <p> 1.8. Анализ поведенческих факторов (сниппеты сайта по запросам, кликабельность в выдаче, поведенческие метрики на сайте). </p>
      </div>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item">
    <a class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__toggle">
      <div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__toggle__number">02</div>
      <span id="heading1">Внешняя оптимизация</span>
    </a>
    <div id="collapse2" class="collapse">
      <div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__descr"> 2.1. Создание проекта в бирже ссылок.<br> 2.2. Внесение продвигаемых страниц.<br> 2.3. Составление анкоров.<br> 2.4. Закупка ссылок в бирже ссылок.<br> 2.4.1 Подбор сайтов-доноров.<br> 2.4.2 Проверка индексации в поисковых системах.<br> 2.4.3 Проверка
        количества внешних ссылок.<br> 2.4.4 Проверка количества внутренних ссылок.<br> 2.4.5 Проверка текстового наполнения сайта.<br> 2.4.6 Проверка посещаемости.</div>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item">
    <a class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__toggle">
      <div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__toggle__number">03</div>
      <span id="heading1">Анализ конкурентов</span>
    </a>
    </p>
    <div id="collapse3" class="collapse">
      <div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__descr"> 3.1. Подбор 4-5 основных конкурентов сайта в интернете.<br> 3.2. Анализ конкурентов с целью поиска сильных мест конкурентов.<br> 3.3. Подготовка технического задания на доработку сайта по результатам анализа конкурентов.</div>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item">
    <a class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__toggle">
      <div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__toggle__number">04</div>
      <span id="heading1">Юзабилити аудит</span>
    </a>
    <div id="collapse4" class="collapse">
      <div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__descr"> 4.1. Анализ основных страниц сайта.<br> 4.2. Анализ конверсионных путей.<br> 4.3. Анализ действия посетителей в корзине.<br> 4.4. Анализ карт поведения посетителей, видеозаписей их активности на сайте.<br> 4.5. Тестирование нововведений при необходимости.<br>        4.6. Подготовка технического задания по результатам юзабилити аудита и контроль внедрения.</div>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item">
    <a class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__toggle">
      <div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__toggle__number">05</div>
      <span id="heading1">Мониторинг</span>
    </a>
    <div id="collapse5" class="collapse">
      <div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__descr">Мониторинг позиций сайта в поисковых системах, посещаемости, конверсий.<br> Фиксация основных параметров сайта и их отслеживание.</div>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item">
    <a class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__toggle">
      <div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__toggle__number">06</div>
      <span id="heading1">Отчеты</span>
    </a>
    <div id="collapse6" class="collapse">
      <div class="page__serviceitem__faq__item__descr">
        <p>Ежемесячное составление отчетов.</p>
      </div>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Поплыло ещё больше...

Comment: @IlyaBurmaka и что именно у вас поплыло?

Comment: перейдите пожалуйста по ссылке http://intellect-media.biz/seo-prodvizhenie/?   внизу там видно

Comment: @IlyaBurmaka обновил ответ

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: здесь работает)За єто , галочка, и спасибо!Но..
Вопрос, почему в обычном html файле не работает, в ошибках увидел это   " Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at"

Comment: @IlyaBurmaka Чтобы корректно отображался блок, замените свой `html` и `css` код для блока `.page__serviceitem__faq` на тот, что в моем примере. А ошибка эта из-за того, что у вас не подключен, либо неверно подключен `jquery`